# Where I have 2 variable in same name one declared as class attribute and another in as parameter (__init__)

Tags: python

```
class student:
    grade = 10

    #instantiate attribute
    def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.grade = grade

obj1 = student("a", 2, 9)

print(obj1.grade, obj1.name, obj1.age)
```

How can I access the **grade** in the *class attribute*

Answer (score 1):

Use `student.grade` (use the actual class name) to do that. However, it's bad habit to have two variables with the same name to do different things as it is bound to create confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The outermost `grade` variable is static and it's same for all instances of `student` class. You can access it via `student.grade` or `obj1.grade`. But, in above case, instance variable overrides the global static variable.
If you want to access it via class instance(i.e. `obj1.grade`), you need to rename local variable to something else.
ps: Generally, it's not good practice to use static variable whenever possible.